# Environment entry duplicated for Web module on WebSphere

Tags: ejb, websphere

My `ear` contains one EJB module and one Web module. One singleton EJB within the EJB module has a String field annotated with `@Resource`:

`@Resource(name = "lecmConfigServiceLookupName")
 private String lecmConfigServiceLookupName;`

The META-INF/ejb-jar.xml specifies a mapping for this environment entry:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="ConfigSingleton">
            <ejb-name>ConfigSingleton</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>ru.brbpm.custom_search_ejb.ConfigSingleton</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Singleton</session-type>
            <init-on-startup>true</init-on-startup>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>lecmConfigServiceLookupName</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>ejb/lecm/common-service.jar/ConfigServiceImpl#ru.brbpm.lecm.shared.api.ConfigServiceRemote</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>`

When I get to deploying the ear to WebSphere 8.5.5.3 I see two identical environment entries - one for the EJB module and the other for the Web module:
[image]

The entry for the web module also does not have the default value and adding an ejb-jar.xml to WEB-INF folder does not help.

How do I get rid of the environment entry for the Web module or at least provide it with a default value? As long as the entry for the Web module is not specified the application will not start.

Comment: Which version of websphere are you using?

Comment: Also how did you packaged your application into an ear?

Comment: This suggests that the ejb-jar.xml file is in the ejb jar and the war WEB-INF so it is being packaged twice, hence being asked to bind the value twice.

Comment: Maybe you added your ejb jar by mistake also to the WEB-INF/lib during packaging?

Comment: The ear is built with maven, and there was no ejb-jar.xml in the war until I tried putting it there to set a default value for the duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - turns out the Web module had an unnecessary transitive dependency on the `ejb-client` of the EJB module. WebSphere was detecting the EJBs in the the ejb-client.jar that was in the Web module's WEB-INF/lib.